# Не понятно почему выдаёт attempt to index a nil value (Lua)

Tags: lua, love2d

В функции love.update(dt) через for я пробегаюсь по таблице buttons где хранятся данные кнопок.

```
function love.update(dt)
    --Buttons clicked
    for k, _ in pairs(buttons) do
        if buttons[k][1]:isClicked() then
            buttons[k]:action()
        end
    end
    --
end
```

Загрузка кнопок происходит так:

```
function Menu:loadScene()
    buttons = {
        Button_1 = {
            Button:new("1", 50, 500),
            action = function()
                Intro:loadScene()
            end
        },

        Button_2 = {
            Button:new("2", 50, 550),
            action = function()
                Intro:loadScene()
            end
        }
    }
end
```

И в этом случае если нажать на кнопку Button_1 то всё нормально, если нажать на Button_2 то выйдет ошибка:

> main.lua:15: attempt to index a nil value
>
> Traceback
>
> main.lua:15: in function 'update' [C]: in function 'xpcall'

А если к примеру создать уже 3 кнопки, то 1 и 2 будут выдавать ошибку а 3 работать. Что тут не так?

[Ссылка с демонстрацией проблемы на ютубе](https://youtu.be/iAqmg3bLsnY)

[Скачать исходники](https://workupload.com/file/f9EwpN5bjwB)

Comment: помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в buttons[k]:action() вызывается  Intro:loadScene(), где затирается глобальная таблица  buttons :

```
function Intro:loadScene()
    buttons = {
        
    }
end
```

Comment: Да, но ведь с одной из кнопок работает

Comment: Да и даже если туда добавить кнопку (в Intro:loadScene()) проблему это никак не исправит

Comment: после первого нажатия вся таблица затирается, повторный вызов love.update(dt) не сможет обойти ее

Comment: А есть альтернативные способы как это реализовать? В теории

Comment: а что именно хотите сделать когда в Intro:loadScene() стираете таблицу? нужно именно убрать кнопки?

Comment: если с таблицей что-то происходит, то нужно проверять buttons на `nil` в love.update(dt) при обходе, например так `if buttons[k] and buttons[k][1]:isClicked() then ` , тоже самое и в love.draw()

Comment: А тогда одна из кнопок всегда работает и не важно что дальше происхдит - затирание таблицы иди наличие других элементов в таблице?

Comment: Спасибо помогло if buttons[k] and buttons[k][1]:isClicked() then. Но почему до этого работала одна их кнопок... Очень необычное поведение у Lua бывает

Comment: И насчёт love.draw(), там ошибку не выдаёт

Comment: про  love.draw() - вероятно оно не нужно, я просто так добавил, потому что проверка переменной или элемента таблицы на nil в lua - частая необходимость

Comment: про проверку: я так понимаю что после нажатия на любую кнопку происходит неявный вызов love.update(dt) - отсюда и обращение к пустой таблице. lua тут как раз не при чем.